# Tapping a comment from a nonexistent user crashes the app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

I'm using Android App v1.0.23 on a HTC Velocity 4G running Android 4.0.3.

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/how-do-i-build-a-defensively-focused-battlemind-at-level-1) I've noticed that tapping the comment from user660 instantly crashes the app. I suspect it is because they don't exist any longer!

Comment: Since this one is now marked as status-completed, perhaps the dupe link should go the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a missing check on users that no longer exist while tapping on a comment.  This should be fixed in the next release rolling out in the next 48 hours:  v1.0.25  Thanks for the report!