# Tapping a comment from a deleted user is reliably crashing the app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app, deleted-accounts

[This comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46218/what-is-the-weight-of-a-laden-adventurer#comment91044_46218) reliably crashes the Android app v1.0.47 every time I tap it. I'm not sure it's the fact they're a deleted user, but every other comment is fine.

This is on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2. This may be a regression of the following bug, introduced with the new top-menu tap handling feature: [Tapping a comment from a nonexistent user crashes the app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225810/tapping-a-comment-from-a-nonexistent-user-crashes-the-app)

Comment: Worth to mention it's working fine in the iOS app.

Comment: Just to be clear, is it simply tapping on the comment or tapping on it and hitting "View Profile" that's causing the crash?

Comment: @Kasra Simply tapping the comment. I wanted to tap it to upvote it, and I can't do that in the app.

Comment: @doppelgreener hmm okay, tapping it doesn't crash on my newest dev build but hitting "View Profile" did, which I just fixed. I can also upvote the comment on my newest dev build.

Comment: @Kasra I've just thought to actually send through a crash report (using the report button in the crash dialog). Looks like it might not be necessary to find out where it's coming from now though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this (and a related crash when hitting `View Profile`) is fixed for the next update, 1.0.48, coming out soon.